# How to display Gridview data based on Dropdown selection that exists on the Gridview itself?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I have data similar to

**PLAN    OPTION   VALUE**
Plan1    option1    10
Plan1    option2    20
Plan2    option1    50
Plan2    option2    70
Plan3                    99

I want a GridView to group similar Plans and have a dropdown showing the Options. Selecting an option will show a different value in the third column.

Plan   |   dropdown with [option1] and [option2])     |   the value driven by the dropdown selection.

What's the best way to do this ?

I hope I was clear.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your aspx file

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1"  AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Plan" HeaderText="PLAN" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="OPTION">                    
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="-1">select</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Option1</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="2">Option2</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="VALUE">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

### Your aspx.cs file

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack) CreateTable();        
}
public void CreateTable()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Plan", typeof(string)));
    dt.Rows.Add("Plan1");
    dt.Rows.Add("Plan1");
    dt.Rows.Add("Plan2");
    dt.Rows.Add("Plan2");
    dt.Rows.Add("Plan3");
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();

} 
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList drp1 = (DropDownList)sender;
    Label lbl = new Label();
    GridViewRow grow = (GridViewRow)(drp1).Parent.Parent;
    lbl = (Label)grow.FindControl("Label1");
    lbl.Text = "bind  " + drp1.SelectedItem.Text + "  value here";      
}
```